# How to get more than only the earliest 1000 transactions record on Etherscan?

Tags: blockchain, transactions, internal-transactions

I am trying to get the data for NFT Trades of a contract address and it ranges from January 12th to February 1st, but the earliest 1000 record is all from January 12th. I need all the data within the range if possible. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?  For tips on forming a good question please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i tried the csv export but seeing that i could use the api key to pull data

Comment: Which CSV export?  Please read the link I posted.

Comment: Basically from this page and I input the range of dates i need: https://etherscan.io/exportData?type=nft-trades